# Testing Android app on real device with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm a bit confused as to how testing on a real Android device works. I hooked up my device (Samsung Galaxy S4) and set the app to run on it, and it works fine. Then I make some changes, and click 'Run' again... but that just brings up the old copy of the app (prior to my changes). Currently the only way I know how to get the updated version of the app on my device for testing, is to manually uninstall the app via Settings before clicking 'Run' again.

Is there a way to shortcut this process and have my updated copy of the app replace the old copy each time I run it?

Comment: it should update. check the log in the various consoles.

Comment: What should I expect the log to say if it is updated vs not?

Comment: there should be some log related to the install of the package on the device. This is done using adb. It should mentioned the name of the package, and end with the booting of the app. If it fails, it should include a message telling you why. typical reasons are lack of space, wrong app version number, different signature.